# How to run tests for OSS Hibernqte Validator on Linux

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, hibernate-validator

I started fiddling around [Hibernate Validator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator), OSS Project in order to fork it later. But I cannot run the tests locally. I followed the official documentation for [Contributing to Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/contribute/) which has a section for **Building from Source**.

##### So why asking on SO instead?

I've been rumbling about this for a couple of months now and last weekend, a friend decided to look into it. Initially, it failed just as with on my PC. But he checked out the `8.0.1.Final` tag and it succeeded.

So late last night, I tried it and failed. It happens that:

- he is on Windows, using JDK 17 from Oracle vs. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with Oracle JDK 17
- previously, I failed with Graal VM for JDK 19, OpenLogic's JDK 17
- he's on Maven `3.9.3` and I tried on `3.9.0` & `3.9.4`

Some module test passed with Maven `3.9.4` & Oracle's JDK 17:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.4 (dfbb324ad4a7c8fb0bf182e6d91b0ae20e3d2dd9)
Maven home: /home/salathiel/.local/bin/maven
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /home/salathiel/.local/opt/jdk-17.0.8
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.2.0-26-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

##### Personal Reflections

I do not think a Java project as Hibernate is made to be developed on Windows only, nor compiled with a specific JDK version/edition. I must be missing on something fundamental.

##### Enough whining

I'm concerned with two weird exceptions:

- NoClassDefFound
- JavaSecurityException

Here is the stack trace:

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[ERROR] Tests run: 982, Failures: 963, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 24.262 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] testUnknownProviderConfiguredInValidationXml(org.hibernate.beanvalidation.tck.tests.bootstrap.customprovider.BootstrapNonAvailableValidationProviderTest)  Time elapsed: 0.037 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestException: 

Expected exception of type class jakarta.validation.ValidationException but got java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
    at org.hibernate.beanvalidation.tck.tests.bootstrap.customprovider.BootstrapNonAvailableValidationProviderTest.testUnknownProviderConfiguredInValidationXml(BootstrapNonAvailableValidationProviderTest.java:58)
```

[...]

```
Expected exception of type class jakarta.validation.ValidationException but got java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
    at org.hibernate.beanvalidation.tck.tests.xmlconfiguration.versioning.UnknownVersionInValidationXmlTest.testValidationXmlWithUnknownSchemaVersion(UnknownVersionInValidationXmlTest.java:43)
```

[...]

```
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 982, Failures: 963, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I would check to run your build with JDK 8...

Comment: The POM requires JDK 11 but the README reads `You will also need a JDK 17+ and Maven 3 (>= 3.3.1).`

Answer (score 0):

Maven revolves around **goals** which are composable (eg.: `test` goals is made of `compile` goal, same is true for `install` and `test`, respectively).

AFAIK, `install` goal will `test`, `compile`, `package` and `copy artifact to local repository`.

In order to avoid the latter side effect (polluting my local repository because it is shared across projects), I have been doing <del>`mvn clean test`</del>... Until this morning:

```bash
# More tests passed with this
mvn clean install
```

`hibernate-validator-distribution` then failed with:

> hibernate-validator-distribution: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

I had `JAVA_HOME="..."` in both my **~/.bashrc** and **~/.ondirrc** but the fix was:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"
```

*NOTE TO SELF: I guess I don't know what I don't know.*